# Google Chrome: the userdata\default folder has disappeared

Tags: google-chrome

I regularly back up my Windows 10 PC to an external disk using a script which uses robocopy to "sync" the data in select folders to the disk.
One script backs up my Chrome profile thus:

```
robocopy  "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" "M:\backups\Emerald\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" /PURGE /DCOPY:T /E /r:0 /log:"M:\backups\logfiles\%LOGFILENAME%"  /MT:4 /xj /np /V
```

However, the last time I did the backup, I got this error:

```
2022/11/26 12:30:30 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked and this is true, the "Default" folder is no longer there. With further investigation, I think that the default profile is now in a folder named "Profile 1".
I did some googling and could find no information indicating that Chrome had changed from using "Default" to "Profile 1".
Can someone in the know point me to any relevant information?
Thanks.